# getting segmentation fault in local machine and online ides works perfectly for a dynamic programming solution

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17, dynamic-programming

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef priority_queue<int> maxHeap;
typedef priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minHeap;
#define endl "\n"
#define int long long
#define MOD 1000000007
#define ump unordered_map
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define pie acos(-1)
#define max(x, y) ((x > y) ? x : y)
#define min(x, y) ((x < y) ? x : y)
#define mid(s, e) ((s + (e - s) / 2))

bool test_cases;

struct precompute {
    void compute() {
    }
};

void init(bool k) {
    test_cases = k;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
}

int dp[1000001];

struct test_cases {
    int minSteps(int n) {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        if (dp[n] != -1) return dp[n];
        int nc = n, x1 = INT_MAX;
        while (nc != 0) {
            int dig = nc % 10;
            nc /= 10;
            if (n - dig >= 0 and dig != 0) {
                x1 = min(x1, 1 + minSteps(n - dig));
            }
        }

        return dp[n] = x1;
    }

    void test_case(int test) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
        cout << minSteps(n) << endl;
    }
};

int32_t main() {
    init(false);
    int tc;
    if (test_cases) {
        cin >> tc;
    } else {
        tc = 1;
    }
    struct precompute l;
    l.compute();
    for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
        struct test_cases o;
        o.test_case(i + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The link for the problem is [Removing Digits](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1637).

The code works perfectly fine on ideone, onlinegdb and even on CSES judge. But it gives segmentation fault(code dumped) error on local machine(ubuntu) while using gnu compiler, for big inputs like 999999 or 1000000. Mostly I think its the issue of recursive stack overflow but should it happen ?

Please help.

Comment: I can reproduce the stack overflow, using a different compiler, so it's genuine.

Comment: `n` could be on the order of `10^6`. On every step, `n` cannot be reduced by more than 9. So you have a recursion at least `10^5` levels deep, possibly more. That's highly likely to exhaust the stack.

Comment: `#define int long long` and `int dp[1000001];` is 8 MB. How much stack is allowed a program to have on your system? Note that `#define min(x, y) ((x < y) ? x : y)` and `min(x1, 1 + minSteps(n - dig));` seems to be very inefficient to compute `minSteps(n - dig)` twice. Anyway, this is stylistically very very bad code.